# Python Notepad++ encoding error

Tags: python, encoding, notepad++, codec

I am using Python for the first time and am running into an encoding error that I can't seem to get around.  Here is the code:

```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   #-*- coding: utf -*-
   import pandas as pd
   a = "C:\Users"
   print(a)
```

When I do this, I get:

> File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python Scripts\ImportExcel.py", line
>   5
>       a = "C:\Users"
>          ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in positio n 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

In Notepad++ I have tried all of the encoding options.  Nothing seems to work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Specifically, the problem is that the '\' is an escape character.
If you want to print the string
"C:\Users"
then you have to do it thus:

```
a = "C:\\Users"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good catch! Another way is to use a raw string `r"C:\Users"`.

Comment: Thanks.  Technically, it answers the question posed, but there are several other valid points made here as well.  Hope it gets selected as the "right" answer :)

@Rich James: Check out the course from Dr. Chuck which looks at all of this, and opening files etc. as well- great course and the best Intro course I've taken.
https://www.py4e.com/

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests you're on a Windows machine, but you're using *nix notation for `#!/usr/bin/python`. That line should look something like `#!C:\Python33\python.exe` on a Windows machine, depending on where you've installed Python.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` instead of `#-- coding: utf --`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the encoding in Notepad++, but you also need to tell Python about it.

In legacy Python (2.7), source code is ASCII unless specified otherwise. In Python 3, source code is UTF-8 unless otherwise specified.

You should use the following as the *first* or *second* line of the file to specify the encoding of the source code. The documentation gives:

```
# -*- coding: <encoding> -*-
```

This is the format originally from the Emacs editor, but according to [PEP263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/#proposed-solution) you can also use:

```
# vim: set fileencoding=<encoding>:
```

of even:

```
# coding=<encoding>
```

Where `<encoding>` can be any encoding that Python supports, but `utf-8` is generally a good choice for portable code.